# Is civi automatically adding recurrence to contributions?

Tags: civicontribute, paypal

We've had a really high number of recurring contributions this month. I started becoming worried because some of the amounts are quite high. Doing some digging, it appears that everyone who used paypal to register in the past month has a recurring contribution set. I tried to run a test, but the payment wouldn't go through (for some reason civi is deleting the "sandbox" portion of the URL when I click save. Any idea what's happening there?) In any case, the test appears to have recurrence turned on even though I didn't opt for a recurring payment.

Could this be an issue with our payment settings? Or is there a bug in civi? This bug runs a serious risk of breaking our trust with our members.

We changed over to paypal pro at the beginning of the month, so it really seems that this issue is tied to that change. Credit cards entered on the back-end aren't coming up as recurring, but it appears every single transaction entered on the front end includes recurrence. There's no way 100% of users selected this option. As mentioned, my test appears to confirm this, even though I couldn't complete the payment.

We are running Wordpress 4.5.1 and CiviCrm 4.7.6.

Comment: I've done more digging. First off, it appears that every payment processed since upgrading to CiviCRM 4.7.3 has been recurring, if made from the user front end. This precedes our shift to PayPal pro.
It appears that the contributions aren't actually recurring - they are simply appearing to recur. This is still a serious issue as we have a different process for recurring contributions than for regular contributions.

Comment: Attempting to cancel them (per comment 1) does not work. "The recurring contribution could not be cancelled." Presumably this occurs because the contribution doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was an issue that sounds very much like what you are describing (https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-18277 that is marked as having been fixed as of 4.7.8), but I think you are saying that beyond the source of the first installment, there were actual recurring contribution records created and listed at the bottom of the contributions tab of a given contact that you then are not able to cancel? If that is the case, I would suggest opening a ticket on JIRA - I haven't seen any tickets in this regards.